# How do I get a configurationSection as string?

Tags: configuration, .net-core

I am working with .NETCore 2.0 I want to load a complete configuration-section as string.

To be specific, I want to do Json-Schema validation and my schema is stored in appsettings.json:

```
{
  ...
  "schemas": {
    "project": {
      "title": "Project",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "param1" ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "param1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "param2": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I want to load configuration-section "schemas.project" as string and let Json.NET Schema do the schema parsing.

Something like this:

```
var schemaString = this.configuration.GetSection("schemas.project").Get<string>();
var schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaString);
...
```

Is there a way to load a complete configuration-section as string? Otherwise I'll read in the schema-file as string..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: You are tryin to re-invent already existing functionality. [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration)

Comment: How am I trying to re-invent existing functionality? The links you posted do not show how to load a whole configurationSection as string.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(
    $"schemaString= {Configuration["schemas:project"]}");`

Comment: This is what we tend to call an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: sadly `Configuration["schemas:project"]` returns `null` because it's a section. Your approach does only work for primitive types